# How to get name of the selected checkbox value from id?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have rendered checkboxes and I have rendered selected checkboxes values like below:

```
    <h:selectManyCheckbox id="chkedition" value="#{adcreateBean.selectedEditions}" layout="lineDirection" styleClass="nostyle">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{adcreateBean.editions}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.editionName}" itemValue="#{item.editionID}"/>
  <p:ajax update="dt1" />

    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    <h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{adcreateBean.selectedEditions}" var="it" styleClass="nostyle" width="100%">
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="You have selected :" />
      </f:facet>
     <h:column>
         <h:outputText value="#{it}" />
     </h:column>
     </h:dataTable>
```

My problem is, it displays id of selected value. But I want name(label) of selected value . So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your `itemValue` indeed only passes the edition ID. You need to pass the edition name instead.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.editions}" var="edition" 
    itemLabel="#{edition.name}" itemValue="#{edition.name}"/>
```

Or, just pass the whole `Edition` object.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.editions}" var="edition" 
    itemLabel="#{edition.name}" itemValue="#{edition}"/>
```

You'll only need to create a custom `Converter` which converts between `Edition` and `String`.

Comment: But I have to store editionID in Database. So I have to pass editionID in itemValue.

Comment: Then pass the whole `Edition` object and create a `Converter`.